# hyperledger composer, where are business network stored

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I has been deployed (this awesome deprecated tool named) hyperledger composer. After a couple of days working, click on a network card emit an error and I'm unable to login. After give up, reinstall everything from zero, does not remove this cards. Already deleted ~/compose* files, also teardown fabric and docker containers.

**So my problem have two solutions:**

1. One, find where are composer model and scripts stored to recover.
2. Two, fix and/or remove these files.**

### Question: Where are CTO and js script files stored?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you not to you use Composer as it is has been deprecated. Please read here. https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/README.md